# Is there a method to access the data itself in SAS like R?

Tags: sas

There are some data in R itself such as Standford heart transplant. Isn't the same in SAS? How can I get the same data at SAS?
Is there a method to access the data itself in SAS like R?

I'm new in SAS and I can't run this code:

```
proc phreg data=stanford;
model survival*dead(0)=transpl surgery age;
run;
```

Comment: Start R, export the data frame to a csv file, import it in SAS, run your model

Comment: Are you trying to access the data supplied with R?  Or how to access sample datasets that SAS provides?  If the later then SAS has a number of datasets it provides in the SASHELP library. For example there is a version of the Framingham Heart Study available as SASHELP.HEART.

Comment: Each application has it's own "internal" sample data sets. In fact, each R package contains it's own and some versions of datasets are not the same in different packages. SAS sample data sets are stored in the SASHELP library, and include several common data sets. If you're looking to explore the usages of a particular PROC, the documentation has fully worked examples that you can use. Notice the link under the title to the full code version. https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_phreg_examples03.htm&locale=en

Comment: The data set is initially sourced from here with some modifications, you can adapt it to your needs. http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/stanford I would probably suggest exporting the one from R instead, especially if you're trying to ensure you get the same results. FYI - there are two copies of that data set floating around that have the same name but are different as per the link.

Answer (score 3):

You have the sasHelp library.

It contains both views on the metadata (e.g. SASHEP.VTABLE and SASHEP.VTABLE) and example datasets (e.g. SASHEP.CAR and SASHEP.CLASS)